# Why does windows 10 crash/reboot after a few minutes of sleep?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, sleep, windows-to-go

I've got a Dell XPS which crashes/reboots a few minutes after entering sleep. Some other facts:

- Running fully updated win 10
- I'm booting Windows To Go (via usb)
- Hibernation is disabled
- There's no log entry related to this. Originally I found: "The system is entering connected standby", so just in case I switched to the disconnected sleep mode - it didn't change the reboot.
- I can successfully sleep when closing the laptop lid and wake up when opening it within maybe 5 min?

Power configuration:

```
The following sleep states are available on this system:
    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Disconnected

The following sleep states are not available on this system:
    Standby (S1)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
        This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

    Standby (S2)
        The system firmware does not support this standby state.
        This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

    Standby (S3)
        This standby state is disabled when S0 low power idle is supported.

    Hibernate
        An internal system component has disabled hibernation.
                Windows To Go

    Hybrid Sleep
        Standby (S3) is not available.
        Hibernation is not available.

    Fast Startup
        Hibernation is not available.

    Standby (S0 Low Power Idle) Network Connected
        Connectivity in standby is disabled by policy.
```

What else can I check?

Comment: `Settings - About - at the bottom Advanced System Setting - Advanced tab - Startup and Recovery Settings` and clear `Automatically Restart`.

Comment: Happens to me with a HP 250 G8, guess it's related to the annoying Connected Standby. I resorted to using Hibertate always... feels like I have a crippled laptop that can't Sleep